# How to allow >(process substitution) when noclobber is set?

Tags: bash

If I have noclobber set in my interactive shell (`set -o noclobber`), I noticed process substitution doesn't work:

```
# echo hello > >(cat)
-bash: /dev/fd/62: cannot overwrite existing file
```

If I turn off noclobber permanently (`set +o noclobber`) it works fine:

```
# echo hello > >(cat)
hello
```

I tried overriding noclobber with `>|` like this:

```
echo hello > >|(cat)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>|'
```

Is there a way to disable noclobber temporarily?

UPDATE: actually, it seems unreasonable for noclobber to take effect when the output goes to process substitution, because there is no file that would be "clobbered". It seems like it would be a good and safe to always use the `>|` and `2>|` overrides to noclobber to prevent "cannot overwrite existing file" errors in case noclobber is inadvertently turned on.

Comment: This may seem obvious, but I was confused by it today and couldn't find a solution online, so I'm creating this question and answer for anyone who might have tripped into the same hole.

Answer (score 3):

Override noclobber in the same way done for files using `>|`:

```
# echo hello >| >(cat)
hello
```

The `>|` must be with the redirection symbol (`>`), not as part of the process substitution (`>(…)`).